# Utilizing Window Size Within Shiny Module

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have several Shiny apps that generate plots with dynamic width/height based on the window size.

My intention has always been to combine all the apps into one app using a combination of `navbar`, `navlist`, `tabPanel`, and modules [as specified here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

A **working** example is given below, *without* utilizing modules:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

# ui.R file below
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$script('
      var dimension = [0, 0];
      $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
      dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
      dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
      Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
      });
      $(window).resize(function(e) {
      dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
      dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
      Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
      });
      ')),

  navlistPanel(        
    tabPanel("Dynamic Dimensions",
             plotlyOutput("myPlot")
    )
  )
)
) 


# server.R file below 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "scatter",
            width = (0.6 * as.numeric(input$dimension[1])), 
            height = (0.75 * as.numeric(input$dimension[2])))
  })

}


# Typically I replace below with run.R file and launch the app in browser
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Due to the large number of app components I'm combining, I've modularized most of my code. This is where I'm having trouble calling the dimensions variable, even when I wrap it in the `ns` function (it appears the dimension is being ignored). Below is the entirety of my code, *unsuccessfully* converted from the above working app. This actually *does* work, but the width is not correctly updated:

myPlot modules:

```
myPlotUI <- function(id, label = "My Plot"){


  ns <- NS(id)


  tags$head(tags$script("
                        var dimension = [0, 0];
                        $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(e) {
                        dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                        dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                        Shiny.onInputChange('dimension', dimension);
                        });
                        $(window).resize(function(e) {
                        dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                        dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                        Shiny.onInputChange('dimension', dimension);
                        });
                        "))

  tagList(
             plotlyOutput(ns("myPlot"))
  )

} 




myPlot <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "scatter",
            width = (0.6 * as.numeric(input$dimension[1])), 
            height = (0.75 * as.numeric(input$dimension[2])))
  })

}
```

Server, UI, and shinyApp:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(myPlot, "myPlot")
}

# ui.R file below 
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

# I've tried putting the js code in this section of the UI. Didn't work...

  navlistPanel(

    tabPanel("Dynamic Dimensions",
             myPlotUI("myPlot")
    )
  )
)
) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any tips on how I can access the window dimensions within a modularized plot object? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that input values accessed by modules are namespaced, while the input values set by `Shiny.onInputChange` are not.

So in the `myPlot` module, `input$dimension` gets `myPlot-dimension` but the input is actually just `dimension`.

One solution would be to make the namespaced id available to the script:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

myPlotUI <- function(id, label = "My Plot") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  dimensionId <- ns("dimension")

  tagList(
    tags$head(tags$script(sprintf("
      var dimensionId = '%s';
      var dimension = [0, 0];

      $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(e) {
        dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
        dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
        Shiny.onInputChange(dimensionId, dimension);
      });

      $(window).resize(function(e) {
        dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
        dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
        Shiny.onInputChange(dimensionId, dimension);
      });
    ", dimensionId))),

    plotlyOutput(ns("myPlot"))
  )
}

myPlot <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "scatter",
            width = (0.6 * as.numeric(input$dimension[1])),
            height = (0.75 * as.numeric(input$dimension[2])))
  })

}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(myPlot, "myPlot")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Dynamic Dimensions",
             myPlotUI("myPlot"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Another solution that comes with a disclaimer: DANGER, undocumented, abuse-prone feature! You can actually get the root session from a module through `session$rootScope()`. Would not recommend unless you really have to, but just FYI.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

myPlotUI <- function(id, label = "My Plot") {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    tags$head(tags$script("
      var dimension = [0, 0];

      $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(e) {
        dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
        dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
        Shiny.onInputChange('dimension', dimension);
      });

      $(window).resize(function(e) {
        dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
        dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
        Shiny.onInputChange('dimension', dimension);
      });
  ")),

    plotlyOutput(ns("myPlot"))
  )
}

myPlot <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  rootInput <- session$rootScope()$input

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "scatter",
            width = (0.6 * as.numeric(rootInput$dimension[1])),
            height = (0.75 * as.numeric(rootInput$dimension[2])))
  })

}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(myPlot, "myPlot")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Dynamic Dimensions",
             myPlotUI("myPlot"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: and also, what is the role of `sprintf', looks like without that function sol1 does not work ? Appreciate if you can explain the use. 2) When I call the module and print dimension, the first print calls NULL and then the next calls width and height value. Looks like the JS renders before shiny load Thank you

Comment: sprintf is used to insert the namespaced input ID (only known on the R side) into the JS script. And right, I believe the dimension input is only set on the `shiny:connected` so it'll be NULL initially.